# How to change Firefox WebDriver Port

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

It is just a curiosity that how can I run firefox driver on different port like IE and Chrome driver.This driver have option like

```
ChromeDriverService service=new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(7000).
                                            usingDriverExecutable(new File("")).build();
```

though the firefox driver have the option like that

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.port","7046");
```

or

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("webdriver_firefox_port",7046);
```

but it can not run firefox driver on this port I am using 2.41 Selenium Webdriver and firefox 31

Can anyone explain why and how can I run firefox driver in specified port.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure, but this should work

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("WebDriver");
profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE, 7046)
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.......I do this before but it was not working but I use default profile "user".....the default profile.

Comment: I also try this after creating a new profile but I got the same result It run on default port 7055 not 7046

Comment: Very interesting, but if use simply FirefoxProfile without getProfile?!, e.g. `FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); profile.setPreference("webdriver.firefox.port", 7046); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);` . I have never faced with such problem =), and very interesting how to solve it.

Comment: I also do this but it can not access the defined port.....Can you please help me to come out from this.

Comment: I'll try to help. 1. Why you need to change your fireFox port? may this is not necessary?  2. What is the main testing process (are you using selenium grid, or just run tests from code). Any other description related to test/and it's purpose will be helpful

Comment: No No It is not related to any test or anything just from curiosity I ask this.