# is there any way to change the webdriver's port?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I'd like to know if there's a way to pass the `--port` argument to the webdriver.

I've already tried this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service_args=['--marionette-port','<PORT>', '--port', '<PORT>'])
```

but it doesn't seem to be working when I add the `--port` argument. It is only working for the `--marionette-port`.

If you go to the terminal and type: `geckodriver --help`, you'll see that you have all these options:

**OPTIONS**:

> -b, --binary            Path to the Firefox binary
>   --log                Set Gecko log level [possible values: fatal, error, warn, info, config, debug, trace]
>   --marionette-host     Host to use to connect to Gecko (default: 127.0.0.1)
>   --marionette-port     Port to use to connect to Gecko (default: system-allocated port)
>   --host                Host ip to use for WebDriver server (default: 127.0.0.1)
>   **-p, --port                Port to use for WebDriver server (default: 4444)**

I'm already running one instance of webdriver in another script. that's why I want to change the port. any help would be great!

Comment: So `-p, --port Port` doesn't get you what you want? Those are the options that allow you to run it on another port.

Comment: no actually, it doesn't. I'm not pretty sure if this is a valid way of doing it. I read a bit about using another firefox profile. but before going that way. I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do it

Comment: Similar question, but for Java: [How to change Firefox WebDriver Port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25491577/3092298).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port of the WebDriver server (i.e. `geckodriver --port`) is controlled by the parameter passed to the [`Service(port=)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.service.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.service). It selects a random port by default, so two scripts running at the same time shouldn't conflict.

In the current stable version of the Python client (3.141.0, released in Nov 2018) `webdriver.Firefox()` (unlike the Chrome variant) doesn't allow specifying a port.

In the upcoming version (you can look up the latest version on [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/pypi/selenium)) it does:

```
#  $ pip install selenium==4.0.0b4
from selenium import webdriver

service = webdriver.firefox.service.Service('geckodriver', port=1234)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

#   $ ps -ef |grep geckodr
#  501 62518 62510   0  6:22PM ttys010    0:00.02 geckodriver --port 1234
```

Comment: Thanks! this is really helpful.

Comment: Hey, sorry but this returns AttributeError: type object 'WebDriver' has no attribute 'Service'. I made sure to have the selenium on 4.0.0.a1 and geckodriver on 0.29.1 and am working on Python 3.6. Any tips?

Comment: @Dante I don't know -- this still works for me (the macOS system I tested this on right now has Python 3.8.2, selenium 4.0.0b4 and geckodriver 0.29.1). Are you sure you're running the exact code provided?

Comment: What happens if I try
`driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(service=webdriver.firefox.service.Service('geckodriver', port=1234))`

`driver2 = webdriver.Firefox(service=webdriver.firefox.service.Service('geckodriver', port=1235))`